# Is it possible to test a drained central heating system without filling it with water

Tags: central-heating, water-circulating-heating

Say there is a house with a just [combination (combi) boiler](https://www.worcester-bosch.co.uk/archive/boilers/what-is-a-combi-boiler) for hot water, but the central heating system has been drained for a couple of years as the house has been uninhabited.

Is it possible to fully test the condition of the central heating system (not the boiler itself, but the hot water infrastructure within the house - i.e. leaks in potentially corroded pipework) without filling the system with water and risk causing said leaks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are just checking for leaks, you can pressurize the system with air, and wait to see if the pressure drops. If it drops, there's a leak somewhere.

Comment: Though this may not be foolproof in case there's a joint that expands with temperature changes.  So it may not leak at room temperature, but then starts leaking at a higher temperature, especially if different materials are involved.  But I would agree that using pressurized air would be a good first test, and probably "good enough".